# How to log file which relays are chosen by Tor browser

Tags: relays, log

Could anyone help me which file need to change in Tor browser if I want to write into a log file which relays are chosen Whenever a new circuit is established?

Comment: Are you using Tor Browser bundle? What type of OS are you using?

Comment: The question seems abandoned. Thus I'll close it. If you have further additions to the question, please [edit](https://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/1757/edit) it and it can be reopened.